# Creating basic HTTP auth with just username no password (from script)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, basic-authentication, .htpasswd

I am trying to replicate Stripe's authentication method which is a basic HTTP authentication but with only users and no passwords (username serves as an API key). However, I am struggling to find a way to create .htaccess files without a password file *from a script* (not a command line). htpasswd either requires a password with using -b parameter or waits for a password from stdin.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to pull it off with use of `openssl passwd` command like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

l1="hereGoesUsername"
l2=":"
l3=`openssl passwd -apr1 ""`

echo $l1$l2$l3 > /path/to/where/the/file/is/.htpasswd
```

This produces entry that allows access by specifying username only and leaving password empty.

Hope it helps someone :).